# Having trouble understanding how running aggregate works

Tags: sql, sql-server

First let me introduce you to an example and after that I'll ask the question.
Code

```
SELECT
    orderyear
   ,qty
FROM
    Sales.OrderTotalsByYear;
```

gives me a table that looks like this

```
orderyear   qty
----------- -----------
2007        25489
2008        16247
2006        9581
```

I need to return for each year the order year, quantity, and running total quantity over the years. That is, for each year, return the sum of the quantity up to that year. So for the earliest year recorded in the view (2006), the running total is equal to that year’s quantity. For the second year (2007), the running total is the sum of the first year plus the second year, and so on.
The code looks like this

```
SELECT
    orderyear
   ,qty
   ,(
        SELECT
            SUM(O2.qty)
        FROM
            Sales.OrderTotalsByYear AS O2
        WHERE
            O2.orderyear <= O1.orderyear
    )
    AS runqty
FROM
    Sales.OrderTotalsByYear AS O1
ORDER BY
    orderyear;
```

and a table

```
orderyear   qty         runqty
----------- ----------- -----------
2006        9581        9581
2007        25489       35070
2008        16247       51317
```

Now, I understand what this code does but I don't understand **HOW** it does it. I have experience in procedural and object oriented programming but this just drives me crazy.
If the query goes in a way like this

> 1. FROM
> 2. WHERE
> 3. GROUP BY
> 4. HAVING
> 5. SELECT
> 6. ORDER BY

then how it manages to combine inner SELECT inside outer SELECT by using relationships between inner and outer SELECT? Is the outer SELECT runned first and it stops when it hits first element inside a table, and then the inner SELECT starts to run for elements where  *O2.orderyear <= O1.orderyear* is true? Or is there something totally different going on?

Comment: Look execution paln u will understand ( but it have too many information )..

Comment: If you want to understand how the query is being processed, execution plans should tell you, but are too broad a subject for a Q+A. SQL has a *logical* processing order, which is the one that you describe. But implementations are free to re-arrange and transform queries to try to satisfy them as cheaply as possible. That's one of the points of SQL - you tell the engine *what*, it works out *how*.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever tnx for the comment. However, I'm not hunting the full understanding of database optimization or execution but just the understand on how to create inner queryes. I'm trying to figure out the sequence of steps I need to take in my head or on paper that will get me to  solution when I'm using inner SELECT. The above code is just given as an example so we can have something concrete to talk about.

Comment: Just a side note: For running totals, you would nowadays rather use an analytic function (`sum() over()`). The same query can be written as: `select orderyear, qty, sum(qty) over(order by orderyear) as runqty from ordertotalsbyyear order by orderyear;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logically**, for each row that the system has generated (via `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`), the system will evaluate the `SELECT` clause. As part of that evaluation of each row, the system will evaluate the correlated subquery:

```
(
    SELECT
        SUM(O2.qty)
    FROM
        Sales.OrderTotalsByYear AS O2
    WHERE
        O2.orderyear <= O1.orderyear
)
```

Using the current row's `O1.orderyear` value.

However, from a *practical* standpoint<sup>1</sup>, the system may be able to optimize its evaluation of this subquery. A smart enough optimizer, if the statistics suggest it is worth doing, may decide to evaluate the outer query in `orderyear` order, and to also create a copy of the `OrderTotalsByYear` table sorted in `orderyear` order (or to make use of an index that already represents this sort order). In such a case, the system would be able to evaluate this subquery result without having to re-scan the entire `OrderTotalsByYear` table for each row of the outer query.

What the optimizer *does* can only be ascertained by obtaining the execution plan, and will depend on your specific tables - their structure, indexes and the data contained within them.

---

<sup>1</sup>SQL is defined in terms of a *logical* processing order. Implementations are free to perform operations in a different order than the logical processing order, provided they produce the same results which would have been obtained if the logical processing order is followed<sup>2</sup>. SQL is also defined, generally, to work on sets rather than to specify row-by-row or left-to-right processing.

<sup>2</sup>SQL Server takes more liberties here than it ought to and may generate errors which would not have been generated *had* it followed the logical processing order. Ho hum.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the query in two steps: The subquery in your select clause is correlated, i.e. it refers to the main query via `O2.orderyear <= O1.orderyear`. So the main query gets executed, and for every single record it reads from the table (aliased O1), it executes the subquery in order to get the running quantity.

So when the main query reads the record for 2008, it executes

```
SELECT SUM(O2.qty)
FROM Sales.OrderTotalsByYear AS O2
WHERE O2.orderyear <= 2008
```

There are two records with a year <= 2008: 2007 and 2008. Their quantities are being added, and thus you get the running total to display with the 2008 record. The same is done for the 2007 and the 2009 record. At last your rows are ordered so as to show the years in ascending order.